# convert table in a pdf file to database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdf

can anyone please give me a suggestion to how can i convert a table in pdf file to a database ?
thanks to everyone for there time

Comment: Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291888/can-i-trun-my-pdf-tables-to-sql-database-or-csv) was already closed because of its low quality... Do not attempt to post another question unless you really improve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have to convert the .pdf file to .csv, then you can import the .csv file into your mysql database as a table.

PDF -> CSV: 
https://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-csv/

Comment: thank you for your feedback but what if my file is kind of not to well organise ? i want to share a type with you

Comment: Your file is recommended to be well-organised, if you want to import into database. It is all about well organisation and logical storement of data.
Maybe you could import to xlsx first, then csv.

Comment: understood thank you for all this informations <3